# Efficient methods to store 2D array/table of data in a SQL database for quick access from php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database-design

A small team of programmers and I are working on a MMO browser game with a large square world map where each index (x, y) refers to a tile on the map. Each tile has a pair of values to store a terrain type id and a randomly generated seed  that will be used for procedural generation. This map will be in the range of 1500x1500 to 500x500 tiles square.

We need an efficient way to store this table on the server, preferably in an SQL database, so that smaller square chunks of the map may be accessed and sent to the player for their browser to render.

The following conditions will always be true about access to the map data.

- The  map data will never be updated once it is stored in the database
- The full map will never be accessed at once
- Only small rectangular portions portions of the map will be accessed in any given query ranging from a single tile to at max a 50x50 square in the table

Given these conditions, what would our options be for storing the data in a MySQL database so that access to rectangular portions of the data will be fast and preferably the same speed regardless of the data's position in the table?

One of our team members came up with this method of layout for a SQL table where each row is a tile in the map:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------| 
|                        table:  map                         | 
|------------------------------------------------------------| 
|      coord       |      tile      | attrs |      seed      | 
|------------------|----------------|-------|----------------| 
|mediumint unsigned|tinyint unsigned| text  |tinyint unsigned| 
|   unique index   |                |       |                | 
|------------------|----------------|-------|----------------|
```

- **coord**: Combination of the X and Y coordinates of the tile on the world map. Calculated via `X + (Y<<11)` for 1500x1500 map.
  (Note that for 50x50 test map, use `X + (Y<<6)`)
- **tile**: The numeric ID of the tile's terrain type
- **attrs**: Any attributes we need to store to modify the tile,
- **seed**: The randomly generated seed for the tile

None of our team members are experienced with SQL table design so we have no way of know if this is a good method or what the bottle necks or slow downs would be

We are looking for an answer that presents our options in the design of our table or tables,  and what the pros and cons of choosing each option would be. Also if you're really nice an example query of pulling a rectangle chunk of the map out of the database (like from (0, 0) to (5, 5)) would be nice.

**EDIT** if there is an option other than MySQL that will be faster such as storing it in a local file on the server that is also a valid answer, however I would like some sort of explanation as to why it would be faster under these conditions

I realize that this is not a simple question and will appreciate any help you may be able to give

Comment: It's not clear to me why you would want to store this in MySql, as opposed to just your own file format on a file system somewhere... you'll never update the data, build queries using the map, report off of map details, etc... seems like throwing MySql into the mix here just complicates it.

Comment: If we store it in a file we have to load the entire file into php memory and read to the position where the data is stored and do this again for every request for the data. It is my understanding that if the table is structured correctly MySQL would be much faster. if this is however not the case then feel free to correct me

Comment: If the map is small enough to fit into php memory, then I would think that would be much faster than querying MySql for the info.  I don't know much about php, but I'm assuming that you have data structures similar to a hash table that you could use to retrieve the info, which would probably be the fastest solution possible.  However, I wouldn't make this decision based on performance... I would go with whatever option is simpler to implement, and then optimize from there if necessary.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I have used flat files for this before and they work fine for simple data, but when you get more complex, such as having multiple layers of tile data for each map, having events on the map, etc. Database tends to be easier to add this complexity with.

Comment: See https://dustinhendricks.com/tenth-tower

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would table it out like this.

**Map Tiles**

```
id - primary key
mapId - indexed
xCoord - indexed
yCoord - indexed
tileId
```

**Maps**

```
id - primary key
tileSetId
```

**Events**

```
id -  primary key
mapId - indexed
xCoord - indexed
yCoord - indexed
proceeduralInstructions
```

The important things are the indexes for look up speed. I added a mapId to the Map Tiles table so that you can store more than one map within this table. The Map table would hold map specific information, like which tileset (image) you are using to draw the map from. Events could be added to the map on rendering. You might come up with a shorthand procedural instruction to place directly into the DB, which can be interpreted by the engine. You would probably also add another table for sprites, and possibly another column to your Map Tile table for which layer the tile is to be painted (some things will appear in front of your characters, while others behind). You may even want two foreground layers and two background layers so that you can layer images with partial transparency on top of each other for richer maps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on why you would use this option. as far as I know we will never need to store more than one map but this is very useful. I take it the providing the index attribute to the fields that will be used to fetch the tile in question is the main source of the look up speed?

Comment: @Ryex Yes, basically it slows down the process of adding new records to the database because it has to re-index the columns, but it increases the look up speed many fold. You'll notice that having multiple maps might be a good thing, since this allows you to play easier with having different tilesets (images) for different areas (ie one tileset for a forest area, one for the desert area, etc), without having to have all of the tilesets loaded at the same time.

Comment: @Ryex after starting to create my own game, I am considering the option of storing the entire map as schema less JSON data in a medium blob, this allows me to make changes on the fly to map data, and have faster read/writes and less indexes. the limitation however is that I would most definitely want to keep each area separated into multiple maps, as each must be loaded in full from the database at once.

Comment: we ended up going with an option very similar to what you described here the only difference being that we combined the x and y concordant into one bit shifted number, as we never need to modify the map this was the best option for us. so far load times of selected areas have been very fast.